# Foreign student with unpaid taxes returning to the US - What are the risks?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, irs, h-1b-visa, immigration

In 2001 I was a foreign student from Haiti, I Studied in the States and my tuition was paid for by my grandfather, so I didn't apply for financial aid and no student loans.

After graduation I worked in Nevada for 2 years under a work permit, the first year I never filed for taxes and never paid taxes either. I was young and ignorant of the fact.

In the 2nd Year, my employer deducted taxes from my paycheck directly but I still didn't file my taxes.

I was forced to leave the US because my work visa had expired, and USCIS had denied my application for renewal.

This year, my family in the United States filed to sponsor me under the Biden Humanitarian Parole program, and I am planning to move to the US because life has been extremely challenging in Haiti.

I have recently been accepted and will be moving to the United States temporarily.

Will my previous Tax issues come back to haunt me, Will I go to Jail? or be deported? or will I owe large sums of money? What next steps should I take before moving to the States?

Comment: Didn't your employer withhold taxes during the first year too? There is a good chance that too much taxes were withheld in the second year and thus you would have gotten a refund if you had filed (though it's too late to get a refund now, but at least you wouldn't owe anything in that case).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about immigration, not personal finance. Consider maybe expats@SE. Generally, you might need to file the missing tax returns and pay the unpaid taxes + penalties, but jail is highly unlikely.